# Error message while opening file in emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I am using Ubuntu and am getting started using emacs. I noticed that I get this error message every time I open a file with emacs.

```
$ emacs index_controller.rb 

** (emacs:1966): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1' failed
```

I'm trying to set it up to use with Ruby on Rails development. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. What do I need to do to get rid of this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is from Gtk. Gtk likes to spew out lots of worrisome-looking messages on standard error; many of them are in fact harmless.

[There's an Ubuntu bug filed about it.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/538499)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an emacs error it's a [theme related error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/538499).

[Resolving "murrine_style_draw_box: assertion `height >= -1'"](http://thehacklist.blogspot.com/2010/06/resolving-murrinestyledrawbox-assertion.html)

> you probably need to modify the gtkrc of the theme which you are using, in order to change the property value below from 0 to 1:
>     GtkRange::trough-under-steppers = 1